# Newsletter formatting lost when sent as email message

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word-2013

I've created a newsletter template in Word 2013 that I distribute via the 'Send to Mail Recipient.'  However, when I receive the mail, most of the page formatting is lost.

This is how I built it in the Word document:

[image: (imgur.com/a/S7ozb)].

But when I receive it in my Outlook, the formatting looks like this:

[image: (imgur.com/a/E5akP)].

What steps do I need to take to ensure that the formatting is preserved?

Comment: sure. so this is how i built it in the word document - [word] (http://imgur.com/a/S7ozb). but when i receive it in my outlook the formatting is not preserved - [outlook] (http://imgur.com/a/E5akP). so i was wondering if i'm missing something here.

Comment: Skewed was the wrong description.  Email generally doesn't have the sophistication to preserve a lot of page formatting details.  I'm not sure what document format is used when you send as email from within Word.  See if there an option to use html, although I'm not sure that will solve it.  One problem is that an email generally doesn't have a defined page size, like a printed document, so it's hard to maintain a layout in an email message.  Your best bet is to send it as an attachment, which will preserve everything.

Comment: Also consider checking things out with a different view. Click on the view ribbon and select the weblayout. I'm not sure whenever this would show you the error but it might help. In addition ... yeha E-Mail doesn't support a lot of HTML stuff.